# Why are these check-boxes not being checked from code-behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC and I have a parameter set to the page in question that specifies what the preceding page is. The reasoning for this is so when a user clicks an image from a particular page, the loaded page will automatically check the appropriate check box using javascript (jQuery particularly).

Here is the code that gets and sets the parameter:

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected string Referrer = string.Empty;
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Referrer = Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[2].ToLower();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {

            Referrer = string.Empty;
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
</script>
```

Next, here is the collection of check-boxes:

```
<div id="interestSelect1" class="interestPad">
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[0])%>
        <label for="Interests_0_">Insulation</label>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[1])%>
        <label for="Interests_1_">Windows</label>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[2])%>
        <label for="Interests_2_">Siding</label>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[3])%>
        <label for="Interests_3_">Roofing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div id="interestSelect2" class="interestPad">
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[4])%>
        <label for="Interests_4_">Gutters/Protection</label>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[5])%>
        <label for="Interests_5_">Patio Doors</label>
    </div>
```

When rendered in the browser, here is what each of the check-boxes look like:

```
<input id="Interests_0_" name="Interests[0]" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Interests[0]" type="hidden" value="false" />
<label for="Interests_0_">Insulation</label>
```

Here is the javascript that I am using, that is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ref = '<%= Referrer %>';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        switch (ref) {
            case "insulation":
                $('Interests_0_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case "windows":
                $('Interests_1_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case "siding":
                $('Interests_2_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case "roofing":
                $('Interests_3_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case "gutters":
                $('Interests_4_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            case "patiodoors":
                $('Interests_5_').attr('checked', 'checked');
                break;
            default:
                // do nothing, not valid ref
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am obviously doing something completely wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Looks like another JS file that was on a MasterPage that was called before my JS block was causing the boxes to not be checked. The main problem was forgetting the `#` identifier.

Comment: @ajreal - your comment seems rather vague to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: my bad, $('Interests_0_').attr('checked', 'checked');
seems need to corrected to $('#Interests_0_').attr('checked', 'checked');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`#id` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) need a `#` prefix, like this:

```
$('#Interests_0_').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Without the `#`, it's an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), looking for a `<Interests_0_>` element.

You can slim it down overall with an object though, like this:

```
var ref = '<%= Referrer %>';
var map = {"insultation":"#Interests_0_",
           "windows":"#Interests_1_",
           "siding":"#Interests_2_",
           "roofing":"#Interests_3_",
           "gutters":"#Interests_4_",
           "patiodoors":"#Interests_5_"};
$(function () {
   var id = map[ref];
   if(id) $(id).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it is still not working properly with that change (which I feel silly for overlooking). Thank you for the object-oriented version of what I had, though, it is very helpful. Also, is `$(function () {});` shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not MVC, but rather classic ASP.NET webforms.  There is no concept of code-behind in MVC, under normal circumstances you don't use events like OnLoad, and you don't normally use runat=server script blocks.  Take a look at the [nerd dinner example](http://tinyurl.com/aspnetmvc) for an overview of MVC.

Comment: I think the OP is just using some names incorrect here, but he *is* using MVC. `<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Interests[0])%>` is not classic webforms.

Comment: That's true, but there's an OnLoad event in there, which certainly isn't MVC.  At best this is a mixture of the two. I think it's more than just using the wrong terminology - maybe this is being ported over from standard webforms?

Comment: @UpTheCreek - Is there some other method I can employ to pass the last segment of the referring URL without using the OnLoad code? That is the only reason I have it in there.

Comment: Well, I blame long day at work. I removed the OnLoad code in favor for `var prodRef = '<%= Request.UrlReferrer.Segments[2].ToLower() %>';` in my <script> block, which does the exact same thing. Thank you for pointing out this best practice, so to speak.

Comment: @Anders: Well, strictly speaking, that code should really go in your controller, and be passed to the view via either a view model or the view data dictionary.  You should keep the view as dumb as possible.  Even with your amended code, your view has to know how the URIs/routes are structured, which it should not be aware of.

Comment: @UpTheCreek - Thank you again for pointing this out, I did rework the code to do everything in the controller.